# IIO: can't open file /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio\:device1/in_voltage_1

Tags: linux, iio

I'm trying to use the raw value from an ADC channel. In my application I do:

```
open("/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio\:device1/in_voltage_1", O_RDONLY);
```

That returns errno 2 "No such file or directory", the file is there though since if I do:

```
$> cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio\:device1/in_voltage_1
```

I get the value I expect.

It also works if I make a soft link:

```
/etc/mylink -> /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio\:device1/in_voltage_1
```

And opens that link instead. The link has the same permissions as the original file.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll leave this up despite of my shame, it may help someone.

It's obviously the backslash in the string argument to open. The path is actually:

```
/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device1/in_voltage_1
```

but the backslash is needed as an escape in the shell.